# Deleting Opposite Values in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2010

I have a database that contains several months' worth of data that needs to be cleaned up before it can be reported. In trying to clean it up, though, I've learned that there are some issues that complicate things significantly. First, the background.

1. There are three status codes that I have to look into: 1 (Approved), 3 (Reversed), and 4 (Reversal).
2. Every status 4 can be attributed to EITHER a status 1 OR a status 3. In a perfect world, status 1 would be changed to status 3 as soon as a 4 is entered, but that doesn't always happen in the timeframe for the reports we get that are then imported to the database.
3. The status 4s have a negative quantity, being a reversal. This quantity cancels out the quantity of the 1 or 3.
4. Each record has two separate identifying numbers, and the 4 status record won't match the 1 or 3 record except having the negative of its quantity and in almost all cases the dates of service will match.
5. Each record also has an identifying customer ID, which helps me match the 4s manually to the 1s and 3s.

Now, the question:

How can I write a query that basically does the following:

IF the date of service and customer ID between two records match, 
AND the quantity of record1 cancels out the quantity of record2 (qtyR1+qtyR2=0) then delete BOTH of the records. Or at least delete the status 1 or status 3 record, because then I could easily write a delete query for the status 4 records.

I'm happy to answer any questions, as I'm not sure I was perfectly clear about the background.

Comment: Have you tried the query design window? How far did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does delete the qtyR1+qtyR2=0 records to begin with:

```sql
DELETE *
FROM myTable A
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM myTable B
        WHERE
            B.CustID = A.CustID AND
            B.Date = A.Date AND
            ((A.Status = 1 AND B.Status = 2) OR (A.Status = 2 AND B.Status = 1)) AND
            A.Quantity + B.Quantity = 0
    )
```

Comment: Thank you all, unfortunately I cannot share even the briefest samples of data because it's got PHI in it for medical stuff, but I believe Olivier's SQL has done the trick. I  have also started reporting that set of data from a different data mart that is supposed to be doing these calculations before setting the data.